# Solving a weird System of equations

Tags: calculus

I have to this weird system.

Find $x,y,z$ three non zeros real numbers (complex solutions are also welcomed) satisfying the following conditions:

$\begin{cases}
x^2=\dfrac{3x-y}{x-3y}\\
y^2=\dfrac{3y-z}{y-3z}\\
z^2=\dfrac{3z-x}{z-3x}
\end{cases}$

My attempt: My basic idea was to show that this numbers does not exist. I’ve shown that $x$ and $ y$ if they exist are positive. But I fail showing $z\ge 0$. Below my work.

Due to symmetry we let   $z\le y\le x (\color{red}{\text{this is pointed out as not valid}})$

Suppose $x<0$:
$x^2=\dfrac{3x-y}{x-3y}$ then $\dfrac{3x-y}{x-3y}\ge0$ therefore  $x-3y<0$ this yields: $x<3y\le 3x$ which can’t be true since $x<0$.  Hence: $\fbox{$x\ge0$}$

Suppose $y<0$:

Then $y-3z<0\Longrightarrow y<3z<3y$ which is false since $y$ is supposed to be negative. Therefore $\fbox{$y\ge 0$}$
Thanks

Comment: if $x=-1$ and $y=-50$ then the logic in your $x<0$ contradiction fails.  $x-3y$ isn't negative.

Comment: The assumption $x \ge 0$ isn't correct. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3D%5Cdfrac%7B3x-y%7D%7Bx-3y%7D

Comment: There is only cyclic symmetry among $x,y,z$ so the assumption $z \le y \le x$ is not correct.

Comment: Okay! Then any idea to solve it.

Comment: If $x=y=z$ then each satisfy $x^2=-1$

Comment: @DavidQuinn In that case we have three complex solutions. What if $x\ne y$?

Comment: Which is explicitly the question? Are $x,y,z$ positive real numbers / do we search for solutions only in positive real numbers?

Comment: @DINEDINE: Your weird system satisfies a weird but perhaps nice property: if $f (x) =\dfrac{t^3-3t}{3t^2-1}$ then the unknowns $x, y, z$ are fixed points of the iterated function 
$F = fofof$, i.e. $F(x)=x$ and so is for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @Piquito can you provide an answer please

Comment: @DINEDINE: What I have wanted to tell you is that you have a direct way of finding a resultant of your system of three unknowns. It is enough that you apply the iteration of three times the function $f$. This will be somewhat cumbersome but straightforward: your three unknowns  $x, y, z$ are roots of $F (t) -t = 0$ where $ F = fofof$. I don't know if this resultant of degree $27$ is irreducible or easily factorable. What I know is that I like this observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints :**

If we solve for $y$, the first equation gives
$$y = \frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}$$

Does this ring a bell? Recall trig formulae and use the periodicity to conclude.

Comment: $x=\tan(\alpha)$ et $y=\tan(3\alpha)$?

Comment: Yes and so on...

Comment: @MyMolecules: Not so on, dear friend, but so what? The system has $23$ real solutions and $4$ non-real ones. Your hints (in plural) have each infinitely many solutions.